# JavaScript: What is the opposite of the logical operator `A && B`?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

In the following code, what is the opposite of the condition `(ran1 <= 63 && ran2 <= 18)`, which should fit in the `else` portion of the `if` statement?

Is it both `(ran1 <= 63 || ran2 <= 18)` and `(! (ran1 <= 63 && ran2 <= 18))`?

Logically, I suppose that the opposite of `A and B` is both `A or B` and `neither A nor B`. But I'm not sure how to express the `neither A nor B` bit in JavaScript.

```
var ran1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var ran2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

if (ran1 <= 63 && ran2 <= 18) {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

Comment: `ran1 > 63 || ran2 > 18` -- you need to inverse every operand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Read on [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mathematical negation of `A && B` is `!A || !B`, so in your case, it would be

```
ran1 > 63 || ran2 > 18
```

Comment: Left to my own devices, I would have come up with `ran1 > 63 && ran2 > 18`. I suppose that `ran1 > 63 || ran2 > 18 ` equates to the idea of "neither A nor B"?

Comment: What you propose is wrong. You can easily verify using an example: ran1 = 64, ran2 = 9. Your original condition is not satisfied, but your proposed is not satisfied either. Standard logic reasoning: `not(A and B)` is the same as `(not A) or (not B)`. Just write a simple table with all values for A and B (just 4: A is either true or false, B also). This is quickly verified :)

Comment: As a side note.  Since we are coding in Javascript and CPU cycle doesn't mean much to most developers/users, but logic similar to this question may be NodeJS and may occur in large batch processing.  So try to put the expression that will fail more frequently first for the && operator and the express that will pass more frequently for the || operator.  This helps improve performance.